# Which effect to use so my texture doesn't look so flat? (Cigar)

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, effects

I am trying to make a realistic cigar texture, but my texture just doesn't seem right. What am I missing, what to do so the texture doesn't look this flat? Any bumps or something? Thank you, btw this my first project so I hope the solution isn't super complicated or something.[image]

Comment: yes give it some bumps, plug your picture into a Converter > RGB to B&W then in a Bump node, also maybe make some parts less glossy

Comment: Was going to suggest the same thing as moonbots; will still reply just to give answers with examples of adding bump: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134371/how-to-add-bump or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81922/is-this-a-correct-way-to-do-procedural-bumps-in-cycles

Comment: maybe share your file so that we can give a try?

Comment: @moonboots Indeed all I did was creating a cylinder and UV  unwrapped this texture onto it. If it is too much work for you (after all you're doing this for free :) ) I can provide the file. just let me know then https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/75/Cigar_Texture.jpg

Comment: @moonboots to your first comment, I am not sure if I did everything right but the texture ends up looking rather like leather than a tobacco leave. And second thing, how to make some part less/more glossy as the others? Is there some "mask layer" as in Photoshop or something? I am sorry, but I am an absolute beginner in Blender.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the kind of node setting that you could use:

Mix a *Diffuse* with a *Glossy*, use the picture as factor of the *Mix Shader*, with a *ColorRamp* between to set the intensity.

Create a displacement picture of your texture with a software like CrazyBump or other, plug this image into the *Height* socket of a *Bump* node, and plug this node into the *Normal* sockets of the *Diffuse* and *Glossy* in order to give a bit of 3D relief.

It needs to be improved of course...

[image]